# How to animate redirection with Solid.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, solid-js

I want to animate my redirection on SPA. I use  for routing I use `@solidjs/router`.
This task is hard for now because in Solid.js component rendering happens after redirection (in my case, maybe this is common behavior.

As for solutions I've tried to create layer - which would tell my parent object to change its class and animate my parent `div`.
Method useBeforeLeave fires at the necessary time, but setting signal and rerendering parent element happens after redirecting...

```ts
// signal created in parent div component and closured in this scope
let transitionUp: Accessor<string>, setTransitionUp: Setter<string>;

const Content: Component<{children: JSX.Element}> = (props) => {
  [transitionUp, setTransitionUp] = createSignal("fadeOut");

  const animHandler = () => {
    if (transitionUp() === "fadeOut") {
      setTransitionUp("fadeIn");
    }
  }

  return (
      <div
          class={`${transitionUp()}`}
          onAnimationEnd={animHandler}
      >
        {props.children}
      </div>
  )
}

const AnimationLayer: Component<{children: JSX.Element}> = (props) => {
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  onCleanup(() => {
    // it happens after element removed from DOM
  });

  useBeforeLeave((e: BeforeLeaveEventArgs) => {
   // this code sets active animation class to parent div
   const transitionStage = transitionUp() === "fadeOut" ? "fadeIn" : "fadeOut";
   setTransitionUp(transitionStage);
  });

  return <>{props.children}</>
}
```

Another solution - try to save parent JSX element in closure and do `JSXel.classList.add(...)` in that function. But it breaks the JSX concept...